# Amplifier with bass, treble and volume contol

Tags: amplifier, stereo

I'm trying to make a an 10 watt stereo amplifier with bass, treble and volume control. I found the schematic of a 10 watt amplifier ( first image ) and a schematic for for the bass, treble and volume control ( 2nd image) my question is how do i combine the 2?
where do i connect the 1st circuit to the 2nd circuit?

[image: Amplifier Circuit]

[image: Pre-amplifier circuit]

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBRwVq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Preamplifier to power amplifier connection is simply a matter of connecting the outputs of one to the inputs of the other.*

One odd thing is that the pots are wired backwards on the BA5406 schematic. Normally they are wired as shown in Figure 1 but this requires log pots (audio taper) so that loudness increases smoothly with rotation. The backwards pots may be a trick to use cheaper linear pots and still give an approximately log response. They actually short out the preamplifier when turned down to zero which is unusual but not dangerous.

Comment: so does that mean i just have to replace the regular 22K pots with 22k log pots?

Comment: Read my answer again. I explained why either would work.

Comment: the backwards pots are 25k, Line In/out used to 10k, when reducing ratio, load attenuates as well as ratio giving a somewhat square law response.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd is an obsolete pre-amp chip  that drives the 1st cct power amp.

Keep looking.

Comment: but will it still work if i use it?

Comment: how about this one http://imgur.com/a/2Jwej